# Wrong sitemap URL getting generated in ATG Endeca

Tags: java, url, sitemap, atg, endeca

I am facing issue in the sitemap URL generation. Even if I have put `< ROLLUP_KEY>product.repositoryId</ROLLUP_KEY>` in my `conf.xml` file.

**The generated URL for pdp page is coming as [this](http://example.com/pdp/flat-sheet-180-threadcount/_/A-sku-10000156__33..337501AB6.catalog10001.en__US.1001?An=0&Au=product.repositoryId)**:

Here sku is getting populated and `product.repositoryId` is also hard coded in all the URLs for both category level and product level urls

**Expected url is**:
http://example.com/pdp/flat-sheet-180-threadcount/_/A-337501AB6

Please suggest any changes since I haven't customized anything at the code level.

Thanks,
Saurabh

Comment: The Oracle Commerce Documentation on how to generate SEO URLs is fairly substantial.  Have you looked at this?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely will want to read the sitemap generator guide, you didn't mention which version of Tools and Frameworks you are running but the configuration files for it will be close to the same across versions.

You will need to modify the xml_template.xml file to format your URL for your pdp under DETAIL_LINK. The

```
**properties**
```

are tag replacements.

```
<DETAIL_LINK><![CDATA[
<url>
   <loc>https//example.org/pdp/**product.description**/_/A-**product.repositoryId**</loc>
</url>
]]></DETAIL_LINK>
```

You could also use the

```
**FORMATTED_URL**
```

which is preferred and explained in the documentation but it uses the configuration setup in url_config.xml to build your URL which is better practice to use.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E66320_01/tools.11-2/EndecaCommerceSitemapdev/EndecaCommerceSitemapdev.pdf#page=18

Comment: Hi Zach, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi @zach, Version for Tools and Framework is 3.1.2 The major issue I am facing is, I'm using FORMATTED_URL and it is generating sku level url instead of product level. <loc>example.com/pdp**FORMATTED_URL|XmlEscape**</loc> Can you please tell me where is it fetching this FORMATTED_URL from, if it is coming from urlconfig.xml then how can we apply ROLLUP_KEY there? Thanks, Saurabh